# Loading data from GCS using Spark Local

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, python-unittest

I am trying to read data from GCS buckets on my local machine, for testing purposes. I would like to sample some of the data in the cloud
I have downloaded the [GCS Hadoop Connector JAR](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/install-storage-connector).

And setup the `sparkConf` as follow:

```py
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setMaster("local[8]") \
    .setAppName("Test") \
    .set("spark.jars", "path/gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar") \
    .set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true") \
    .set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "path/to/keyfile")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config(conf=sc.getConf()) \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.read.json("gs://gcs-bucket")
```

I have also tried to set the conf like so:

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl",  "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "path/to/keyfile")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
```

I am using PySpark install via PIP and running the code using the unit test module from IntelliJ

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o128.json.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue, you need to add configuration for `fs.gs.impl` property in addition to properties that you already configured:

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
```