# Reading a csv file from GCS bucket through Pyspark installed in Anaconda

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I have Anaconda installed and a virtual env. created on Windows. I have installed Spark on windows and followed all the steps at https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md, plus I followed the steps mentioned at StackOverflow:

- [Reading from google storage gs:// filesystem from local spark instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716055/reading-from-google-storage-gs-filesystem-from-local-spark-instance)
- [Loading data from GCS using Spark Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059063/loading-data-from-gcs-using-spark-local)

Even though I don't hadoop cluster I've still placed `core-site.xml` at `$SPARK_HOME/conf` with added property `fs.gs.impl`suggested in the stackoverflow question# `55059063`
Also created variables 
`JAVA_HOME, GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME (both to C:\$SPARK_HOME)`
added `$SPARK_HOME & java8 jdk\bin` to `path` variable. But still I'm getting below error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o147.json.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

core-site.xml

```
  <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl</name>
  <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS</value>
  <description>The AbstractFileSystem for gs: uris.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.impl</name>
  <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem</value>
  <description>The AbstractFileSystem for gs: uris.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.project.id</name>
  <value>my-project-id</value>
  <description>
    Optional. Google Cloud Project ID with access to GCS buckets.
    Required only for list buckets and create bucket operations.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>
    Whether to use a service account for GCS authorization.
    Setting this property to `false` will disable use of service accounts for
    authentication.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile</name>
  <value>C:\path\to\credentials.json</value>
  <description>
    The JSON key file of the service account used for GCS
    access when google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable is true.
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595263/pyspark-error-java-io-ioexception-no-filesystem-for-scheme-gs/55599599#55599599

Comment: Thanks Ranga! But if you see my question I've done all those steps. I've added those properties in ```core-site.xml```

Comment: As you don't need hadoop libs setup, configuring using code is best option.